# query error using Parse javascript sdk

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

In my code I would like to allow the user to delete their images. Here's my code

```
var Image = Parse.Object.extend("Image");
    var query = new Parse.Query(Image);
    query.equalTo('data', image);
    query.find({
      success: function(results) {
        window.result = results;
        console.log('successful query', results, image);
      },
      error: function(error) {
        console.log('Error: ' + error.code + ' ' + error.message);
      }
    });
```

the `results` object keeps returning an empty array. What could be causing this issue?
I'm entering the success branch but it's an empty array. Could there be a limit to the size of the element you select for? this image variable is a datastring for a url it is very long > 12K characters.

Comment: Can you try using the data browser filter feature to search for this item by 'data' ?

Comment: @Fosco interesting. The filter can't perform the operation either. Neither does 'starts with' on 'data' work.

Comment: are you sure it matches 100%?  I don't think searching by this type of field would be good for performance... can you keep track of the objectId and grab the object that way?

Comment: @Fosco yeah switching over to using an image object that also contains an objectid. Question. The query would now be `query.equalTo('objectId', foo)` or `.equalTo('image', foo)`?

Comment: https://www.parse.com/docs/js_guide#queries-relational 'objectId' works but I'd like to use this convenience key if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think searching by this type of field would be good for performance.  Keep track of the objectId and get/destroy the object that way.

```
var query = new Parse.Query("Image");
query.get('object-id-here').then(function(obj) {
  return obj.destroy();
}).then(function() {
  // Image is deleted.
}, function(err) {
  // error condition
});
```